# Hibernate Criteria Pagination Error

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, criteria

In the below code, I am able to retrieve all the desired data without any problem.

```
List<Message> msgList = new ArrayList<Message>();
Criteria crit = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Message.class);
crit.createAlias("processes", "process");
crit.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
Criterion c1;
Criterion c2;
Criterion c3;
Criterion c4;
Criterion c5;
Criterion c6;
Criterion c7;
c1 = Restrictions.like("process.initiator", user.getUserOid()+"%");
c2 = Restrictions.like("process.firstApprover", user.getUserOid()+"%");
c3 = Restrictions.like("process.secondApprover", user.getUserOid()+"%");
c4 = Restrictions.like("process.thirdApprover", user.getUserOid()+"%");
c5 = Restrictions.like("process.finalizedBy", user.getUserOid()+"%");
c6 = Restrictions.or(Restrictions.eq("process.isFinalized", false), Restrictions.isNull("process.isFinalized"));
c7 = Restrictions.eq("account.oid", acountId);
crit.add(Restrictions.and(Restrictions.and(Restrictions.or(Restrictions.or(Restrictions.or(Restrictions.or(c1, c2), c3), c4), c5), c6),c7));
crit.addOrder(Order.desc("latestDate"));
//crit.setFirstResult(first);
//crit.setMaxResults(max);
msgList = crit.list();
```

However, I cannot add pagination to the above data retrieval. When I uncomment the above firstResult and maxResult I encounter the following error:

```
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near '.'.
```

Below is the generated SQL:

```
WITH query AS (select this_.oid as oid24_24_, this_.arsivmi as arsivmi24_24_, this_.arsivzamani as arsivzam3_24_24_, 
 this_.baslik as baslik24_24_, this_.durum as durum24_24_, this_.gonderitipi as gonderit6_24_24_, 
 this_.gonderilmezamani as gonderil7_24_24_, this_.gondermedelil_oid as gonderm22_24_24_, this_.hesap_oid as hesap23_24_24_, 
 this_.hsgondermezamani as hsgonder8_24_24_, this_.ilgilikopya as ilgiliko9_24_24_, this_.kimden as kimden24_24_, 
 this_.kime as kime24_24_, this_.mesajbody as mesajbody24_24_, this_.mesajboyut as mesajboyut24_24_, this_.okunandelil_oid as okunand24_24_24_, 
 this_.okunmazamani as okunmaz14_24_24_, this_.onemli as onemli24_24_, this_.plaintext as plaintext24_24_, this_.silindimi as silindimi24_24_, 
 this_.silinmezamani as silinme18_24_24_, this_.son_islem_tarihi as son19_24_24_, this_.varisdelil_oid as varisdelil25_24_24_, 
 this_.variszamani as varisza20_24_24_, this_.yaratilmazamani as yaratil21_24_24_, this_.kepsmime_oid as kepsmime1_28_24_, 
 this_.kepsmimewrapped_oid as kepsmime2_28_24_, this_.erisimlogoid as erisimlo1_30_24_, this_.kepsmime_oid as kepsmime3_30_24_, 
 this_.kepsmimewrapped_oid as kepsmime4_30_24_, this_.taslakmi as taslakmi30_24_, 
 this_.clazz_ as clazz_24_, kepdelil3_.oid as oid21_0_, kepdelil3_.content_oid as content8_21_0_, kepdelil3_.eventcode 
 as eventcode21_0_, kepdelil3_.islemzamani as islemzam3_21_0_, kepdelil3_.kepmesaj_oid as kepmesaj9_21_0_, kepdelil3_.mime_message_id 
 as mime4_21_0_, kepdelil3_.relevantadress as relevant5_21_0_, kepdelil3_.status as status21_0_, kepdelil3_.tip as tip21_0_, kepdelilco4_.oid 
 as oid22_1_, kepdelilco4_.mime_message_id as mime2_22_1_, kepdelilco4_.refrecordcount as refrecor3_22_1_, kepdelilco4_.smimecontent 
 as smimecon4_22_1_, kepdelilco4_.xmlcontent as xmlcontent22_1_, kepmesaj5_.oid as oid24_2_, kepmesaj5_.arsivmi as arsivmi24_2_, kepmesaj5_.arsivzamani 
 as arsivzam3_24_2_, kepmesaj5_.baslik as baslik24_2_, kepmesaj5_.durum as durum24_2_, kepmesaj5_.gonderitipi as gonderit6_24_2_, kepmesaj5_.gonderilmezamani 
 as gonderil7_24_2_, kepmesaj5_.gondermedelil_oid as gonderm22_24_2_, kepmesaj5_.hesap_oid as hesap23_24_2_, kepmesaj5_.hsgondermezamani 
 as hsgonder8_24_2_, kepmesaj5_.ilgilikopya as ilgiliko9_24_2_, kepmesaj5_.kimden as kimden24_2_, kepmesaj5_.kime as kime24_2_, kepmesaj5_.mesajbody 
 as mesajbody24_2_, kepmesaj5_.mesajboyut as mesajboyut24_2_, kepmesaj5_.okunandelil_oid as okunand24_24_2_, kepmesaj5_.okunmazamani 
 as okunmaz14_24_2_, kepmesaj5_.onemli as onemli24_2_, kepmesaj5_.plaintext as plaintext24_2_, kepmesaj5_.silindimi as silindimi24_2_, kepmesaj5_.silinmezamani 
 as silinme18_24_2_, kepmesaj5_.son_islem_tarihi as son19_24_2_, kepmesaj5_.varisdelil_oid as varisdelil25_24_2_, kepmesaj5_.variszamani 
 as varisza20_24_2_, kepmesaj5_.yaratilmazamani as yaratil21_24_2_, kepmesaj5_.kepsmime_oid as kepsmime1_28_2_, kepmesaj5_.kepsmimewrapped_oid 
 as kepsmime2_28_2_, kepmesaj5_.erisimlogoid as erisimlo1_30_2_, kepmesaj5_.kepsmime_oid as kepsmime3_30_2_, kepmesaj5_.kepsmimewrapped_oid 
 as kepsmime4_30_2_, kepmesaj5_.taslakmi as taslakmi30_2_, kepmesaj5_.clazz_ as clazz_2_, hesap6_.oid as oid2_3_, hesap6_.alanadi as alanadi2_3_, hesap6_.hesaponadi 
 as hesaponadi2_3_, hesap6_.subdomain as subdomain2_3_, hesap6_.subdomainvarmi as subdomai5_2_3_, hesap6_.askitarihi as askitarihi2_3_, hesap6_.durum 
 as durum2_3_, hesap6_.hizmetturu as hizmetturu2_3_, hesap6_.kapatan as kapatan2_3_, hesap6_.kapatmanedeni as kapatma10_2_3_, hesap6_.musteri_oid 
 as musteri13_2_3_, hesap6_.tebligatadresi as tebliga11_2_3_, hesap6_.tip as tip2_3_, musteri7_.oid as oid41_4_, musteri7_.basvuruzamani 
 as basvuruz2_41_4_, musteri7_.crmmusterino as crmmuste3_41_4_, musteri7_.durum as durum41_4_, musteri7_.durumaciklama as durumaci5_41_4_, musteri7_.irtibatnoktasi_oid 
 as irtibatn9_41_4_, musteri7_.tip as tip41_4_, musteri7_.veridogrulamazaman as veridogr7_41_4_, musteri7_.veridogrulamasi as veridogr8_41_4_, musteri7_2_.adres 
 as adres47_4_, musteri7_2_.birimadi as birimadi47_4_, musteri7_2_.hizmetkodu as hizmetkodu47_4_, musteri7_2_.kurumadi as kurumadi47_4_, musteri7_2_.kurumkimlikno 
 as kurumkim5_47_4_, musteri7_2_.vergidairesikodu as vergidai6_47_4_, musteri7_2_.vergino as vergino47_4_, musteri7_3_.adres as adres50_4_, musteri7_3_.anafaaliyetalani 
 as anafaali2_50_4_, musteri7_3_.faks as faks50_4_, musteri7_3_.il_oid as il10_50_4_, musteri7_3_.ilce_oid as ilce11_50_4_, musteri7_3_.kurumadi 
 as kurumadi50_4_, musteri7_3_.merkez_il as merkez12_50_4_, musteri7_3_.telefon as telefon50_4_, musteri7_3_.ticaretsicilno 
 as ticarets6_50_4_, musteri7_3_.vergidairesikodu as vergidai7_50_4_, musteri7_3_.vergino as vergino50_4_, case when musteri7_1_.oid is not null then 1 
 when musteri7_2_.oid is not null then 2 when musteri7_3_.oid is not null then 3 when musteri7_.oid is not null then 0 end as clazz_4_, irtibatnok8_.oid 
 as oid46_5_, irtibatnok8_.ad as ad46_5_, irtibatnok8_.eposta as eposta46_5_, irtibatnok8_.gorevi as gorevi46_5_, irtibatnok8_.soyad as soyad46_5_, irtibatnok8_.tel1 
 as tel6_46_5_, irtibatnok8_.tel2 as tel7_46_5_, irtibatnok8_.unvan as unvan46_5_, sehir9_.oid as oid67_6_, sehir9_.ad as ad67_6_, sehir9_.plakakodu 
 as plakakodu67_6_, province10_.oid as oid66_7_, province10_.ad as ad66_7_, province10_.sehir_oid as sehir3_66_7_, sehir11_.oid as oid67_8_, sehir11_.ad 
 as ad67_8_, sehir11_.plakakodu as plakakodu67_8_, sehir12_.oid as oid67_9_, sehir12_.ad as ad67_9_, sehir12_.plakakodu as plakakodu67_9_, hesaphizme13_.oid 
 as oid4_10_, hesaphizme13_.arsivhizmet_oid as arsivhiz5_4_10_, hesaphizme13_.blarsivhizmeti as blarsivh2_4_10_, hesaphizme13_.blkriptolamahizmeti 
 as blkripto3_4_10_, hesaphizme13_.blvirushizmeti as blvirush4_4_10_, hesaphizme13_.hesap_oid as hesap6_4_10_, hesaphizme13_.kriptolamahizmet_oid 
 as kriptola7_4_10_, hesaphizme13_.virushizmet_oid as virushiz8_4_10_, arsivhizme14_.oid as oid10_11_, arsivhizme14_.aciklama as aciklama10_11_, arsivhizme14_.kota 
 as kota10_11_, kriptolama15_.oid as oid11_12_, kriptolama15_.aciklama as aciklama11_12_, kriptolama15_.hesaptip as hesaptip11_12_, virushizme16_.oid 
 as oid12_13_, virushizme16_.aciklama as aciklama12_13_, virushizme16_.hesaptip as hesaptip12_13_, rehbersorg17_.oid as oid57_14_, rehbersorg17_.hesap_oid 
 as hesap2_57_14_, rehbersorg17_.ad as ad58_14_, rehbersorg17_.adres as adres58_14_, rehbersorg17_.hizmetalmasekli as hizmetal3_58_14_, rehbersorg17_.il 
 as il58_14_, rehbersorg17_.ilce as ilce58_14_, rehbersorg17_.soyad as soyad58_14_, rehbersorg17_.telefonnumarasi as telefonn7_58_14_, rehbersorg17_.adres 
 as adres59_14_, rehbersorg17_.kurumadi as kurumadi59_14_, rehbersorg17_.adres as adres60_14_, rehbersorg17_.anafaaliyetalani as anafaali2_60_14_, rehbersorg17_.islemyetkilisiad 
 as islemyet3_60_14_, rehbersorg17_.islemyetkilisisoyad as islemyet4_60_14_, rehbersorg17_.islemyetkilisiunvan as islemyet5_60_14_, rehbersorg17_.kurumadi 
 as kurumadi60_14_, rehbersorg17_.merkez_il as merkez7_60_14_, rehbersorg17_.mersisno as mersisno60_14_, rehbersorg17_.clazz_ as clazz_14_, kepdelil18_.oid 
 as oid21_15_, kepdelil18_.content_oid as content8_21_15_, kepdelil18_.eventcode as eventcode21_15_, kepdelil18_.islemzamani as islemzam3_21_15_, kepdelil18_.kepmesaj_oid 
 as kepmesaj9_21_15_, kepdelil18_.mime_message_id as mime4_21_15_, kepdelil18_.relevantadress as relevant5_21_15_, kepdelil18_.status as status21_15_, kepdelil18_.tip 
 as tip21_15_, kepdelil19_.oid as oid21_16_, kepdelil19_.content_oid as content8_21_16_, kepdelil19_.eventcode as eventcode21_16_, kepdelil19_.islemzamani 
 as islemzam3_21_16_, kepdelil19_.kepmesaj_oid as kepmesaj9_21_16_, kepdelil19_.mime_message_id as mime4_21_16_, kepdelil19_.relevantadress as relevant5_21_16_, kepdelil19_.status 
 as status21_16_, kepdelil19_.tip as tip21_16_, kepsmime20_.oid as oid34_17_, kepsmime20_.smimecontent as smimecon2_34_17_, kepsmime20_.kepsigncontent 
 as kepsignc3_34_17_, kepsmime20_.refrecordcount as refrecor4_34_17_, kepsmime20_.smime_package_id as smime5_34_17_, kepsmime20_.usersigncontent as usersign6_34_17_, kepsmime21_.oid 
 as oid34_18_, kepsmime21_.smimecontent as smimecon2_34_18_, kepsmime21_.kepsigncontent as kepsignc3_34_18_, kepsmime21_.refrecordcount 
 as refrecor4_34_18_, kepsmime21_.smime_package_id as smime5_34_18_, kepsmime21_.usersigncontent as usersign6_34_18_, process1_.oid as oid37_19_, process1_.arsivbpmnts 
 as arsivbpm2_37_19_, process1_.arsivbpmnurl as arsivbpm3_37_19_, process1_.arsivemailts as arsivema4_37_19_, process1_.arsivemailurl as arsivema5_37_19_, process1_.arsivftpts 
 as arsivftpts37_19_, process1_.arsivftpurl as arsivftp7_37_19_, process1_.arsivvarmi as arsivvarmi37_19_, process1_.birincionaybilgilendirme 
 as birincio9_37_19_, process1_.bpmntetiklendimi as bpmntet10_37_19_, process1_.deadline as deadline37_19_, process1_.durationmaxday as duratio12_37_19_, process1_.finalnote 
 as finalnote37_19_, process1_.finalts as finalts37_19_, process1_.finalizedby as finaliz15_37_19_, process1_.firstapprovaldone as firstap16_37_19_, process1_.firstapprovalroles 
 as firstap17_37_19_, process1_.firstapprovalts as firstap18_37_19_, process1_.firstapprover as firstap19_37_19_, process1_.firstapproversnote 
 as firstap20_37_19_, process1_, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by this_.son_islem_tarihi desc) as __hibernate_row_nr__.fromfilter as fromfilter37_19_, process1_.hesap_oid 
 as hesap48_37_19_, process1_.ikincionaybilgilendirme as ikincio22_37_19_, process1_.initialnote as initial23_37_19_, process1_.initialts as initialts37_19_, process1_.initiator 
 as initiator37_19_, process1_.isfinalized as isfinal26_37_19_, process1_.kimden as kimden37_19_, process1_.kime as kime37_19_, process1_.mesaj_oid as mesaj49_37_19_, process1_.notified 
 as notified37_19_, process1_.secondapprovaldone as seconda30_37_19_, process1_.secondapprovalroles as seconda31_37_19_, process1_.secondapprovalts 
 as seconda32_37_19_, process1_.secondapprover as seconda33_37_19_, process1_.secondapproversnote as seconda34_37_19_, process1_.subject as subject37_19_, process1_.subjectfilter 
 as subject36_37_19_, process1_.tag_oid as tag50_37_19_, process1_.tcknovkn as tcknovkn37_19_, process1_.thirdapprovaldone as thirdap38_37_19_, process1_.thirdapprovalroles 
 as thirdap39_37_19_, process1_.thirdapprovalts as thirdap40_37_19_, process1_.thirdapprover as thirdap41_37_19_, process1_.thirdapproversnote as thirdap42_37_19_, process1_.tofilter 
 as tofilter37_19_, process1_.treshold as treshold37_19_, process1_.ucuncuonaybilgilendirme as ucuncuo45_37_19_, process1_.versiyon as versiyon37_19_, process1_.yon 
 as yon37_19_, hesap23_.oid as oid2_20_, hesap23_.alanadi as alanadi2_20_, hesap23_.hesaponadi as hesaponadi2_20_, hesap23_.subdomain as subdomain2_20_, hesap23_.subdomainvarmi 
 as subdomai5_2_20_, hesap23_.askitarihi as askitarihi2_20_, hesap23_.durum as durum2_20_, hesap23_.hizmetturu as hizmetturu2_20_, hesap23_.kapatan as kapatan2_20_, hesap23_.kapatmanedeni 
 as kapatma10_2_20_, hesap23_.musteri_oid as musteri13_2_20_, hesap23_.tebligatadresi as tebliga11_2_20_, hesap23_.tip as tip2_20_, kepmesaj24_.oid as oid24_21_, kepmesaj24_.arsivmi 
 as arsivmi24_21_, kepmesaj24_.arsivzamani as arsivzam3_24_21_, kepmesaj24_.baslik as baslik24_21_, kepmesaj24_.durum as durum24_21_, kepmesaj24_.gonderitipi 
 as gonderit6_24_21_, kepmesaj24_.gonderilmezamani as gonderil7_24_21_, kepmesaj24_.gondermedelil_oid as gonderm22_24_21_, kepmesaj24_.hesap_oid 
 as hesap23_24_21_, kepmesaj24_.hsgondermezamani as hsgonder8_24_21_, kepmesaj24_.ilgilikopya as ilgiliko9_24_21_, kepmesaj24_.kimden as kimden24_21_, kepmesaj24_.kime 
 as kime24_21_, kepmesaj24_.mesajbody as mesajbody24_21_, kepmesaj24_.mesajboyut as mesajboyut24_21_, kepmesaj24_.okunandelil_oid as okunand24_24_21_, kepmesaj24_.okunmazamani 
 as okunmaz14_24_21_, kepmesaj24_.onemli as onemli24_21_, kepmesaj24_.plaintext as plaintext24_21_, kepmesaj24_.silindimi as silindimi24_21_, kepmesaj24_.silinmezamani 
 as silinme18_24_21_, kepmesaj24_.son_islem_tarihi as son19_24_21_, kepmesaj24_.varisdelil_oid as varisdelil25_24_21_, kepmesaj24_.variszamani 
 as varisza20_24_21_, kepmesaj24_.yaratilmazamani as yaratil21_24_21_, kepmesaj24_.kepsmime_oid as kepsmime1_28_21_, kepmesaj24_.kepsmimewrapped_oid 
 as kepsmime2_28_21_, kepmesaj24_.erisimlogoid as erisimlo1_30_21_, kepmesaj24_.kepsmime_oid as kepsmime3_30_21_, kepmesaj24_.kepsmimewrapped_oid as kepsmime4_30_21_, kepmesaj24_.taslakmi 
 as taslakmi30_21_, kepmesaj24_.clazz_ as clazz_21_, kepmesajta25_.oid as oid25_22_, kepmesajta25_.icon as icon25_22_, kepmesajta25_.name as name25_22_, kepmesajta25_.hesap_oid 
 as hesap1_26_22_, kepmesajta25_.clazz_ as clazz_22_, hesap26_.oid as oid2_23_, hesap26_.alanadi as alanadi2_23_, hesap26_.hesaponadi as hesaponadi2_23_, hesap26_.subdomain 
 as subdomain2_23_, hesap26_.subdomainvarmi as subdomai5_2_23_, hesap26_.askitarihi as askitarihi2_23_, hesap26_.durum as durum2_23_, hesap26_.hizmetturu as hizmetturu2_23_, hesap26_.kapatan 
 as kapatan2_23_, hesap26_.kapatmanedeni as kapatma10_2_23_, hesap26_.musteri_oid as musteri13_2_23_, hesap26_.tebligatadresi as tebliga11_2_23_, hesap26_.tip as tip2_23_ 
 from ( select oid, arsivmi, arsivzamani, baslik, durum, gonderitipi, gonderilmezamani, hsgondermezamani, ilgilikopya, kimden, kime, mesajbody, mesajboyut, okunmazamani, onemli, plaintext, 
 silindimi, silinmezamani, son_islem_tarihi, variszamani, yaratilmazamani, gondermedelil_oid, hesap_oid, okunandelil_oid, varisdelil_oid, kepsmime_oid, kepsmimewrapped_oid, null 
 as erisimlogoid, null as taslakmi, 1 as clazz_ from kepmesajgelen union all select oid, arsivmi, arsivzamani, baslik, durum, gonderitipi, gonderilmezamani, hsgondermezamani, ilgilikopya, 
 kimden, kime, mesajbody, mesajboyut, okunmazamani, onemli, plaintext, silindimi, silinmezamani, son_islem_tarihi, variszamani, yaratilmazamani, gondermedelil_oid, hesap_oid, okunandelil_oid, 
 varisdelil_oid, kepsmime_oid, kepsmimewrapped_oid, erisimlogoid, taslakmi, 2 as clazz_ from kepmesajgiden ) this_ left outer join kepdelil kepdelil3_ on this_.gondermedelil_oid=kepdelil3_.oid 
 left outer join kepdelilcontent kepdelilco4_ on kepdelil3_.content_oid=kepdelilco4_.oid 
 left outer join ( select oid, arsivmi, arsivzamani, baslik, durum, gonderitipi, gonderilmezamani, hsgondermezamani, ilgilikopya, kimden, kime, mesajbody, mesajboyut, 
 okunmazamani, onemli, plaintext, silindimi, silinmezamani, son_islem_tarihi, variszamani, yaratilmazamani, gondermedelil_oid, hesap_oid, okunandelil_oid, varisdelil_oid, kepsmime_oid, kepsmimewrapped_oid, null 
 as erisimlogoid, null as taslakmi, 1 as clazz_ from kepmesajgelen union all select oid, arsivmi, arsivzamani, baslik, durum, gonderitipi, gonderilmezamani, hsgondermezamani, ilgilikopya, 
 kimden, kime, mesajbody, mesajboyut, okunmazamani, onemli, plaintext, silindimi, silinmezamani, son_islem_tarihi, variszamani, yaratilmazamani, gondermedelil_oid, hesap_oid, okunandelil_oid, 
 varisdelil_oid, kepsmime_oid, kepsmimewrapped_oid, erisimlogoid, taslakmi, 2 as clazz_ from kepmesajgiden ) kepmesaj5_ on kepdelil3_.kepmesaj_oid=kepmesaj5_.oid 
 left outer join hesap hesap6_ on kepmesaj5_.hesap_oid=hesap6_.oid left outer join musteri musteri7_ on hesap6_.musteri_oid=musteri7_.oid left outer join bireyselmusteri musteri7_1_ on musteri7_.oid=musteri7_1_.oid 
 left outer join kamumusteri musteri7_2_ on musteri7_.oid=musteri7_2_.oid left outer join tuzelmusteri musteri7_3_ on musteri7_.oid=musteri7_3_.oid 
 left outer join irtibat_noktasi irtibatnok8_ on musteri7_.irtibatnoktasi_oid=irtibatnok8_.oid left outer join sehir sehir9_ on musteri7_3_.il_oid=sehir9_.oid 
 left outer join province province10_ on musteri7_3_.ilce_oid=province10_.oid left outer join sehir sehir11_ on province10_.sehir_oid=sehir11_.oid 
 left outer join sehir sehir12_ on musteri7_3_.merkez_il=sehir12_.oid left outer join hesaphizmet hesaphizme13_ on hesap6_.oid=hesaphizme13_.hesap_oid left outer join arsivhizmet 
 arsivhizme14_ on hesaphizme13_.arsivhizmet_oid=arsivhizme14_.oid left outer join kriptolamahizmet kriptolama15_ on hesaphizme13_.kriptolamahizmet_oid=kriptolama15_.oid 
 left outer join virushizmet virushizme16_ on hesaphizme13_.virushizmet_oid=virushizme16_.oid 
 left outer join ( select oid, hesap_oid, ad, adres, hizmetalmasekli, il, ilce, soyad, telefonnumarasi, null as kurumadi, null as anafaaliyetalani, null as islemyetkilisiad, null 
 as islemyetkilisisoyad, null as islemyetkilisiunvan, null as merkez_il, null as mersisno, 1 as clazz_ from bireyselrehbersorgulanabilir union all select oid, hesap_oid, null as ad, 
 adres, null as hizmetalmasekli, null as il, null as ilce, null as soyad, null as telefonnumarasi, kurumadi, null as anafaaliyetalani, null as islemyetkilisiad, null as islemyetkilisisoyad, null 
 as islemyetkilisiunvan, null as merkez_il, null as mersisno, 2 as clazz_ from kamurehbersorgulanabilir union all select oid, hesap_oid, null as ad, adres, null as hizmetalmasekli, null as il, null 
 as ilce, null as soyad, null as telefonnumarasi, kurumadi, anafaaliyetalani, islemyetkilisiad, islemyetkilisisoyad, islemyetkilisiunvan, merkez_il, mersisno, 3 
 as clazz_ from tuzelrehbersorgulanabilir ) rehbersorg17_ on hesap6_.oid=rehbersorg17_.hesap_oid left outer join kepdelil kepdelil18_ on kepmesaj5_.okunandelil_oid=kepdelil18_.oid 
 left outer join kepdelil kepdelil19_ on kepmesaj5_.varisdelil_oid=kepdelil19_.oid left outer join kepsmime kepsmime20_ on kepmesaj5_.kepsmime_oid=kepsmime20_.oid 
 left outer join kepsmime kepsmime21_ on kepmesaj5_.kepsmimewrapped_oid=kepsmime21_.oid inner join workflowprocess process1_ on this_.oid=process1_.mesaj_oid 
 left outer join hesap hesap23_ on process1_.hesap_oid=hesap23_.oid left outer join ( select oid, arsivmi, arsivzamani, baslik, durum, gonderitipi, gonderilmezamani, 
 hsgondermezamani, ilgilikopya, kimden, kime, mesajbody, mesajboyut, okunmazamani, onemli, plaintext, silindimi, silinmezamani, son_islem_tarihi, variszamani, yaratilmazamani, 
 gondermedelil_oid, hesap_oid, okunandelil_oid, varisdelil_oid, kepsmime_oid, kepsmimewrapped_oid, null as erisimlogoid, null as taslakmi, 1 as clazz_ from kepmesajgelen union all select oid, 
 arsivmi, arsivzamani, baslik, durum, gonderitipi, gonderilmezamani, hsgondermezamani, ilgilikopya, kimden, kime, mesajbody, mesajboyut, okunmazamani, onemli, plaintext, silindimi, silinmezamani, 
 son_islem_tarihi, variszamani, yaratilmazamani, gondermedelil_oid, hesap_oid, okunandelil_oid, varisdelil_oid, kepsmime_oid, kepsmimewrapped_oid, erisimlogoid, taslakmi, 2 as clazz_ from kepmesajgiden ) 
 kepmesaj24_ on process1_.mesaj_oid=kepmesaj24_.oid left outer join ( select oid, icon, name, hesap_oid, 1 as clazz_ from kepmesajcustomtag union all select oid, icon, name, null as hesap_oid, 2 as clazz_ 
 from kepmesajsystemtag ) kepmesajta25_ on process1_.tag_oid=kepmesajta25_.oid left outer join hesap hesap26_ on kepmesajta25_.hesap_oid=hesap26_.oid 
 where ((((((process1_.initiator like ? or process1_.firstapprover like ?) or process1_.secondapprover like ?) or process1_.thirdapprover like ?) or process1_.finalizedby like ?) 
 and (process1_.isfinalized=? or process1_.isfinalized is null)) and this_.hesap_oid=?) ) SELECT * FROM query WHERE __hibernate_row_nr__ >= ? AND __hibernate_row_nr__ < ?
```

Comment: First paste your whole query generated by hibernate

Comment: Can you show us the generated SQL?

Comment: I have updated the question and added the generated SQL. Can you please check it?

Comment: Have u checked your `first` and `max` ? Are they containing appropriate values ?

Comment: Yes, they are set correctly. Also I statically set them as 0 and 10 but the code still fails.

Comment: Is it recomneded that you have to use `Criteria` .Try `hql` it will be a cleaner approach .You are making 7 `Criterions`

Comment: With HQL the above code is handled and it is working correctly but I have other methods where I have more than 25 Criterions to feed into Criteria. I have to use pagination in Criteria into that methods. Isn't there any workaround?